# Performing a SUM when value could exist in one of a few different columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Assume there is a simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[foo](
    [foo_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
        [val1_id] [int] NULL,
        [val1_amount] [int] NULL,
        [val2_id] [int] NULL,
        [val2_amount] [int] NULL,
        [val3_id] [int] NULL,
        [val3_amount] [int] NULL,
        [val4_id] [int] NULL
        [val4_amount] [int] NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

And there is some other table that is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[val](
    [val_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
        [amount] [int] NOT NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The user of the application will select an entry from the table val, and the application will place val_id and amount in val?_id and val?_amount in a non-deterministic manner (yes, I know this isn't good, but I have to deal with it).

Is there a way to produce output that will group by the val_id from the foo table and SUM the amount values from the foo table, given that the val_id/amount may be stored in any of the val?_id/val?_amount columns?  Note that if val_id is stored in val1_id, the amount will always be stored in val1_amount within that row, but the same val_id may appear in a different val?_id in a different row (but the amount will be in the corresponding column)

Comment: So, is your row basically full of id/value pairs? Also, find whoever set it up this way and hit them really hard. Honestly, if there's any opportunity for you to change this table to something competent, you should do so. Each pair should be a row in a table with a foo_id FK column.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, after you smacked the guy that designed this, you can try to `UNPIVOT` your columns, and then simply `SUM` the `val_amount` resultant column. I'm not gonna actually use [`UNPIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), but I'm doing the same with `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT x.Val_id, SUM(x.val_amount) Val_Amount
FROM dbo.foo t
CROSS APPLY 
(
    VALUES
        (t.val1_id, t.val1_amount),
        (t.val2_id, t.val2_amount),
        (t.val3_id, t.val3_amount),
        (t.val4_id, t.val4_amount)
) x (Val_id, val_amount)
GROUP BY x.Val_id;
```

[**Here is a sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1bc2d/4) with a live demo for you to try.

Answer (score 1):

I did it using the COALESCE function.  I'm not clear why I had to do a nested query, but I couldn't get it to take it otherwise:

```
select id, sum(amount)
FROM 
   (SELECT COALESCE(val1_id , val2_id , val3_id , val4_id) id, 
       COALESCE(val1_amount , val2_amount , val3_amount , val4_amount) amount  
    from foo) coalesced_data 
GROUP BY ID
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2ef35/6

Comment: Because at the same scope you can't aggregate on an alias you just created. The SELECT is parsed in one shot, not character by character. You should have been able to say `SELECT id, SUM(COALESCE(,...,) ... GROUP BY COALESCE(,...,)` but that's arguably worse than a subquery simply for readability.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to produce output that will group by the val_id from the foo table and SUM the amount values from the foo table, given that the val_id/amount may be stored in any of the val?_id/val?_amount columns?

Hell is other people's data. You might do something like this:

```
create view FOO as
select foo.id, val1_id as valueid, val1_amount as amt from T
union all
select foo.id  val2_id as valueid, val2_amount as amt from T
union all
select foo.id  val3_id as valueid, val3_amount as amt from T
union all
select foo.id  val4_id as valueid, val4_amount as amt from T
```

Comment: If performance matters, then a problem with this technique is that it requires four individual table access operators (scan or seek) so will always perform at least 4 times worse than other methods (such as the two other answers so far).

Comment: Yes, if the table is very large it could perform poorly. But I don't think one can say that it would perform "at least 4 times worse". If the table is not large it has the advantage of simplicity.

Comment: All other things being equal, 4 times the number of reads is 4 times worse. I can't see any other way to slice it. If the table is small, then perhaps "performance doesn't matter", as you suggest. But if it *does* matter, then I can' t see the `UNION ALL` method as being very viable when there are other, better methods. In my opinion, simplicity is not enough of a benefit to outweigh the disadvantages.

Comment: About the blunt calculation "4 times worse" -- cache could be involved, so on subsequent reads the table could be in memory and would not involve further disk reads. It all depends on circumstances that were not provided by the OP. Think of my solution to the problem as generic and portable across multiple versions of SQL including legacy versions. The OP is dealing with a pile of shite and the solution was offered in that context.

Comment: Tim, your answer definitely is a fair one. No downvote here. :) I simply commented about performance based on my experience with the `UNION` technique as *always* being inferior in performance, in *real world tested scenarios*, than methods that do it all in one go.

Answer (score 0):

If you have correctly stated that the value will *only ever* appear in one pair of `(val_id, val_amount)` columns leaving the other 3 pairs blank, then this will work better than the currently accepted answer (@lamak's)

```
select id = coalesce(val1_id, val2_id, val3_id, val4_id),
       val = sum(coalesce(val1_amount, val2_amount, val3_amount, val4_amount))
from foo
group by coalesce(val1_id, val2_id, val3_id, val4_id);
```

It is easy to understand and even though the COALESCE is repeated, it is really only evaluated once so there is no performance penalty.  The query plan is estimated at 50% the cost of the other query.

[The currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16153389/573261) may also produce a phantom NULL row, for example for the data in my SQL fiddle demo that does not contain anything in the 3rd pair (val3_amount).

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/53080/4/0)